# when i inspect the web page ....i m going to form.less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, less

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
       <tr>
          <td width="224" bgcolor="#DEECF5"> <div align="right"><font color="#FF0000">*</font>

           <b>Address :</b></div></td>
           <td bgcolor="#DEECF5"> <input type="text" name="address"  class="form-control" value="<?php print $dataary['address'];?>">
            <br>
            <?php print $errors['address']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </div>
</form>

href="css/bootstrap3.3.7/css/less/form.less
```

Can I give this file in my code?

Actually i have aplly my css to ttttt.css but when I inspect the textbox I'm getting to the form.less

Now i want my `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/form.less` ....

This path to be local file system.

So can u also provide correct bootstrap path example 
please provide the bootstrap path for forms.lss
and My textbox width for address is also large in size

Comment: When i inspect the element ...i m getting my css style of bootstrap https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/form.less and i have given the link of this only.but if i want to give link of <link href="css/bootstrap3.3.7/css/less/form.less " can i give this file in my code ?
    Actually i have aplly my css to ttttt.css but when i inspect the textbox i m getting to the form.less 
    now i want my https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/form.less ....this path to be local file system ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i want to remove the link of href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/less/forms.less](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971573/i-want-to-remove-the-link-of-href-https-maxcdn-bootstrapcdn-com-bootstrap-3-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the file form `https://github.com/caolan/bootstrap-less/blob/master/bootstrap/forms.less` and store it in your local.